How to define a function based on the platform in MAUI?
In my .NET8 MAUI application, I have a few functions for every platform but most of the code is the same. I saw somewhere that I could do something like:
#if iOS
    public async Task<string> Register(NSData rawToken)
    {
        var nativeToken = rawToken.ToPushTokenString();
#endif
#if ANDROID
    public async Task<string> Register(string nativeToken)
    { 
#endif
        // code
    }

I tried but Visual Studio disagrees and gets me an error. Is there any particular configuration I have to change? How does this pre-processor command work?
Update
The errors are:

CS1519 Invalid token 'return' in class, record, struct, or interface member declaration
CS1022 Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected



"Visual Studio disagrees and gets me an error." What error?

You used a build configuration that is neither for iOS nor ANDROID so you got invalid uncompilable code?

You should also checkout the "official" guidance on these things - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/single-project?view=net-maui-8.0#platform-specific-code

You could just add a private method that actually handles the token:
#if iOS
public async Task<string> Register(NSData rawToken)
{
    var nativeToken = rawToken?.ToPushTokenString();
    return await HandleTokenAsync(nativeToken);
}
#elif ANDROID
public async Task<string> Register(string nativeToken)
{ 
    return await HandleTokenAsync(nativeToken);
}
#endif

private async Task<string> HandleTokenAsync(string token)
{
    // do whatever you need to do here and return the result
}

This could also be simplified to:
#if iOS
public Task<string> Register(NSData rawToken) => HandleTokenAsync(rawToken?.ToPushTokenString());
#elif ANDROID
public Task<string> Register(string nativeToken) => HandleTokenAsync(nativeToken);
#endif

private async Task<string> HandleTokenAsync(string token)
{
    // do whatever you need to do here and return the result
}

Generally, though, I think that it's better to not have two method signatures, but instead have different implementations per platform, if necessary at all. You should probably make the call to rawToken?.ToPushTokenString() before passing the argument to the Register() method, that will leave you with a cleaner API and moves the responsibility of using the correct argument to the caller.
Now, you need to make sure that all compilation targets have valid, compilable code. If the platform is neither Android nor iOS, your code will not compile, because you have a missing method signature and opening braces, which leads to invalid code blocks.

Try to change your code:
#if iOS
public async Task<string> Register(NSData rawToken)
{
    var nativeToken = rawToken.ToPushTokenString();
    // code...
}
#elif ANDROID
public async Task<string> Register(string nativeToken)
{ 
    // code
}
#endif

Maybe you have to think about other build configurations also (WINDOWS, for example).

Yes but in this case I duplicate the code like now.

I would refactor the code to use partial classes instead of what you have right now.

namespace LanguageInUse.Services.PartialMethods
{
    public partial class DeviceInstallation
    {
        public async Task<string> Register(string token);
    }
}


android:
namespace LanguageInUse.Services.PartialMethods
{
    public partial class DeviceInstallation
    {
        public async Task<string> Register(string token) {
            // do something
        }
    }
}


ios:
namespace LanguageInUse.Services.PartialMethods
{
    public partial class DeviceInstallation
    {
        public async Task<string> Register(string token) {
            var nativeToken = NSData.FromString(token).ToPushTokenString();
            // do something
        
        }
    }
}


make sure your namespaces are same across all. With this you don't need to add these if everywhere. Because currently how it's setup you need to add #if iOS everywhere to send an NSData and so on.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/invoke-platform-code?view=net-maui-8.0
